# Pandas dataframe create new row for every value over multiple columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe with unique values in ID column.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['A', 'B', 'C'],
                   'STAT': ['X', 'X', 'X'],
                   'IN1': [1, 3, 7],
                   'IN2': [2, 5, 8],
                   'IN3': [3, 6, 9]})
```

I need to create a new dataframe where I have a row for each value in IN1, IN2 and IN3 with corresponding ID and STAT:

```
df_new = pd.DataFrame({'IN': [1, 2, 3, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
                       'ID': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
                       'STAT': ['X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X', 'X']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`pandas.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html):

```
(pd.wide_to_long(df, ['IN'], j='to_drop', i='ID')
   .droplevel('to_drop')
   .sort_index()
   .reset_index()
)
```

output:

```
  ID STAT  IN
0  A    X   1
1  A    X   2
2  A    X   3
3  B    X   3
4  B    X   5
5  B    X   6
6  C    X   7
7  C    X   8
8  C    X   9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `melt`

```
df.melt(id_vars=['ID','STAT'], value_name='IN')
```

Gives:

```
ID  STAT    variable    IN
0   A   X   IN1 1
1   B   X   IN1 3
2   C   X   IN1 7
3   A   X   IN2 2
4   B   X   IN2 5
5   C   X   IN2 8
6   A   X   IN3 3
7   B   X   IN3 6
8   C   X   IN3 9
```

To make the df into a row:

```
(df.melt(id_vars=['ID','STAT'], value_name='IN')
   .sort_values(by='ID')
   .drop('variable', axis=1)
)
```

Gives the exact same results.

Comment: You did not need the `.T` ;)